# If/Else Statements or Equations?

Tags: c++, performance, if-statement, equation

## Questions:

Is it generally at all better to use if statements or equations when dealing with boolean values? Please address the following questions, keeping in mind that your answer should apply to most, if not all code:

1. Which is faster, and why? Or is the difference too small to be significant?
2. Is one of them more dynamic? Is there a reason one of them may fall short to the other in certain scenarios?
3. Which is the better/preferred code, or is the practice of either entirely opinion based?

(I am referring to C++, but as this question is semi-generic, references or comparisons to other languages would also be appreciated.)

## Example (in C++):

Given the following broad scenario,

```
int n = (anything);
bool x_not_y = (declared as random boolean value);
```

And the goal being to make `int x = n` if `x_not_y` is true and `int y = n` instead on the contrary, is it better to use an **if/else statement**:

```
if (x_not_y)
    x = 5;
else
    y = 5;
```

(shorthand below)

```
x_not_y?x = 5:y = 5;
```

or to use an **equation**?

```
x = (x * (int)!x_not_y) + (5 * (int)x_not_y);
y = (y * (int)x_not_y) + (5 * (int)!x_not_y);
```

Comment: An interesting question. At first I thought the answer was obvious but now I want to wait and see what someone much more experienced than me thinks!

Comment: I risk getting yelled at by the premature optimization guys, but the answer is: "it depends on lots of things"

Comment: There are no "equations" in C++. There are only *statements*, which are comprised (among other things) of *expressions*.

Comment: @Mysticial - beat me to it.  Also, bear in mind that your compiler is (almost always) phenomenally smarter than you :)

Comment: Well i will guess that the first one is faster, due to branch prediction and as no calculation is going on, the first one is also much betteri n terms of readability IMO and last but not least, isnt the outcome of both different? In the first, one var is unmodified, in the second snippet both are modified

Comment: Most hacks around branch prediction optimizations do not conform to the C standard, and thus tend to be compiler-dependent.

Comment: Sorry they came across as different, I modified the example accordingly. @Mystical if that's the case, thank you! That's all I wanted to know.

Comment: I would do `(x_not_y ? x : y) = 5` :)

Comment: I would not make any optimization recommendations until seeing the context surrounding this code.  It may be necessary to optimize, or you may need a reality check.

Comment: So what I've gathered is that there's nothing to worry about regarding efficiency (for the most part), and that there's no specific advantage to using an equation format.

Comment: @JimHurley It's very hard to know without seeing how you intend to apply it.  What are your efficiency requirements?  How many million times per second does it get called?  If you don't know, then don't optimize.  Clear, readable code is your first priority.

Comment: Thank you, Paddy, I wish I could mark that as my answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Which is faster, and why? Or is the difference too small to be significant?

I doubt such code would make a difference to modern optimizers, but if you want to know, we first would have to ask, *What platform, what compiler?*, and then we would need to measure.

> Is one of them is more dynamic? Is there a reason one of them may fall short to the other in certain scenarios?

As I happen to believe that your compiler's optimizer can deal with all of them equally, I would suggest to write code that's easy to understand and maintain and deal with optimizations only after measuring reveals that this is a hotspot.

> Which is the better/preferred code, or is the practice of either entirely opinion based?

Over time, I have found that I am leaning more and more towards the functional paradigm. I like expressing branches through the code's structure better than through variable values, I prefer to constify as much as possible (even locale variables).

I have especially learned to dislike code like this:

```
int x;
if( some_condition )
    x = 5;
else
    x = 42;
```

In order to understand what code like this does, one has to track the values  of each variable and follow each statement. Also, `x` cannot be `const` here, which I consider a string disadvantage.

I strongly prefer

```
const int x = calc_x(some_condition);
```

which, in cases as easy as this example, can be written as

```
const int x = some_condition ? 5 : 42;
```

Now `x` can be `const` (allowing the compiler to prevent me from unintentionally doing silly things), the piece of code implementing the algorithm that finds out what `x` ought to be has a name (`calc_x()`), and rather than having the algorithm `inline`, now only that name is in the code.

Of course, this code is so simple that it doesn't really need the benefits I am listing, but when you deal with more complex real-world code, I have found that, in the long run, a more functional approach is be better.

Comment: The question is about performance when setting two different values, given one condition.

Comment: Am I right in saying that along with avoiding algorithms that are inline, you also prefer the code to (if possible) be made in one statement, to account for `const`'s?

Comment: @paddy: I tried to change my answer to address all three questions. But really, I'd dismiss the first two anyway.

Comment: @Jim: It's not only the `const`. I'd likely use this even if `x` couldn't be `const` (because it's changed further down in the code). Still, thinking about it, I guess I try to minimize altering the values of variables, even if they are non-const, and prefer structural statements (`if`, `while` etc.) over that. But, yes, I also prefer giving even simple algorithms names (by turning them into functions). Inlining makes this abstraction come at zero cost.

Comment: I suppose it must really just generally be code-specific as no one has said "this, not that," but I will absolutely take this advice.

Answer (score -1):

Your two examples do two different things:

The IF statement changes x or y, leaving the other unchanged.

Your equation changes both x & y, setting one to the value `5` and the other to `0`.

That said, the if statement may suffer a branch misprediction penalty, where the second form would not (at the cost of being hard to read).

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer

Comment: This comment is getting a lot of upvotes.  I don't see anything answering the question.

Comment: This answer is wrong. If variables are declared previously, refer to the last bit of code.

Comment: To avoid confusion I removed the 2 options and left just the one your answer addressed